# How to convert '1*1 char' to a logical vector in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

Actually I'm trying to convert hex to bin.

```
a=hex2dec('ab32');  
a=dec2bin(a);
%now I have a 1to1 char array of for example 1010101...
%I want to have an 1*16 array of 1 and 0's
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Can't test this right now so I'm not posting it as an answer, but have you tried casting (the elements of) the array to [`int8`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/int8.html) or `uint8` or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this:

```
a=logical(a-'0')
```

Example:

```
octave:224> a=hex2dec('ab32')
a =  43826
octave:225> a=dec2bin(a)
a = 1010101100110010
octave:226> a=logical(a-'0')
a =

   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   0

octave:227> whos a
Variables in the current scope:

   Attr Name        Size                     Bytes  Class
   ==== ====        ====                     =====  ===== 
        a           1x16                        16  logical

Total is 16 elements using 16 bytes

octave:228>
```

Comment: Actually you don't even need the `real` - I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This gives you a 1*16 vector of reals, all either 0 or 1:

```
(dec2bin(hex2dec('ab32'))-'0')
```

while this gives you a 1*16 vector of logicals, all either false or true (which look like 0s and 1s)

```
(dec2bin(hex2dec('ab32'))-'0')==1
```